# Looking for a Specific Cocoa Logging Framework

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, logging

Lately there was a really nice Cocoa logging framework around. It had a GUI so you can log images and a nice presentation for data blobs etc. But I can't remember the name and cant find it with google.

Anyone knows which framework I'm looking for? A link to it would do it. thx.

-edit-

Its not:

- cocoalumberjack
- Log4Cocoa
- SOLogger

Comment: Perhaps a list of the ones you did find (I found several with "cocoa logging framework") so we're not wasting our time naming them for you?

Comment: Suggested title: "Dude, where's my logging framework?"  "It was like totally at this party and I totally saw this thing, it was like, totally awesome, and it did a bunch of stuff...  What was that called?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found It!!! It was NSLogger https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger