# NSLog() to both console and file

Tags: objective-c, nslog

I would like to redirect `NSog()` to file, but still to see the output in console.
I am aware that `stderr` can be redirected to file using:

```
freopen("file.log", "a+", stderr);
```

but after redirecting it to file, the log is no more shown in the console output.

I could build a custom wrapper around `NSLog()` but I would not get logged crash logs that are written to `stderr` in the moment of app crash.

I was also experimenting with `dup()` and other methods for duplicating file descriptors, but the output was ether in file or in console, never in both.

Similar questions was asked here:
[Write stderr on iPhone to both file and console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577318/write-stderr-on-iphone-to-both-file-and-console)
but without accepted answer, or with suggestion to use a NSLog() wrapper.

Has anyone an idea on how to manage this work?
Thanx in advance.

**UPDATE:** The most important part of redirecting is to have system error logs (**stderr**) written to both console and file.

Comment: What if you do two separate logs, send one to file, and one to console, but keep them the same?

Comment: How do you suggest to manage this? The most important thing is to have system error logs written to both console and file.

Comment: `NSLog` by default logs to console, maybe you could just extract your logs from there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150849/how-can-i-get-a-console-readout-at-runtime-in-an-application/7151773#7151773

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that you were doing this for error logs, I skimmed through and assumed it was just use of NSLog

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIGDBJC), you will need a custom log facility.

You need at a minimum, a function that takes variadic arguments and printd to NSLog and fprintf, something like:

```
void myLog(NSString* format, ...)
{
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, format);
    NSString* formattedMessage = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: format arguments: argList];
    va_end(argList);
    NSLog(@"%@", formattedMessage);
    fprintf(myFileDescriptor, "%s\n", [formattedMessage UTF8String]);
    [formattedMessage release]; // if not on ARC
}
```

Or there are Cocoa logging frameworks.

[Looking for a Specific Cocoa Logging Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440297/looking-for-a-specific-cocoa-logging-framework)

Comment: Thanks, this is good, but check my updated question. I am looking for some way to get system's stderr logs to both console and file, not only my custom logs. Thanks.

Comment: @Miroslav: I don't think that's possible without a similar change to what I have given you.

Answer (score 35):

The way we have implemented is:

```
if (!isatty(STDERR_FILENO)) {
    // Redirection code
}
```

This is based on general assumption that if a console is attached, you do not need to store those logs in the file since you are already debugging. So whenever the console is attached, logs will be printed there, otherwise saved to a file.