# Test for NSLog output

Tags: xcode, xctest

I'm writing a framework that also includes a simple logger that can be enabled/disabled at runtime. Since I want have unit tests for as much of the framework as possible, I also want to test whether the logger works correctly.

The logger simply logs via `NSLog`. Now I need to test whether the output really matches the expectation (i.e. does it really log and is the output in the correct format). I couldn't find a way to do that using Xcode's XCTest framework.

I could modify the logger so that it doesn't use `NSLog` while testing but that strikes me as error-prone. So, is there a better way to check the `NSLog` output?

Comment: I'm new to TDD so can you explain what the reason of testing system API in your project instead of mocking NSLog and test code around it

Comment: and as answer you can check this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/9619708/1403732 where asker told that he redirected `NSLog` stream to file. I think it's good starting point for you

Comment: I do _not_ want to test whether `NSLog` works, I want to test whether the logging is correctly done, until the very end. That involves checking the output of `NSLog`, if possible. Redirecting might indeed be a way to investigate. It would probably hide most/all output from the testing environment itself so I must redirect just for the test and then restore redirection… it's something I should play around with. Had thought about it before but missed the point that I can probably restore redirection after my test.

Comment: @sage444: So I did solve it by redirecting the file descriptor. Thanks for making me think about that again :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by writing a utility class that redirects a file descriptor to a file and is able to reset this redirection:

```
@interface IORedirector : NSObject

- (instancetype)initWithFileDescriptor:(int)fileDescriptor targetPath:(NSURL *)fileURL flags:(int)oflags mode:(mode_t)mode;

- (void)reset;

@end

@implementation IORedirector
{
    int _fileDescriptor;
    int _savedFileDescriptor;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFileDescriptor:(int)fileDescriptor targetPath:(NSURL *)fileURL flags:(int)oflags mode:(mode_t)mode
{
    _savedFileDescriptor = dup(fileDescriptor);
    if (_savedFileDescriptor == -1) {
        NSLog(@"Could not save file descriptor %d: %s", fileDescriptor, strerror(errno));
        return nil;
    }

    int tempFD = open(fileURL.path.fileSystemRepresentation, oflags, mode);
    if (tempFD == -1) {
        NSLog(@"Could not open %@: %s", fileURL.path, strerror(errno));
        close(_savedFileDescriptor);
        return nil;
    }

    if (close(fileDescriptor) == -1) {
        NSLog(@"Closing file descriptor %d failed: %s", fileDescriptor, strerror(errno));
        close(_savedFileDescriptor);
        close(tempFD);
        return nil;
    }

    if (dup2(tempFD, fileDescriptor) == -1) {
        NSLog(@"Could not replace file descriptor %d with new one for %@: %s", fileDescriptor, fileURL.path, strerror(errno));
        close(_savedFileDescriptor);
        close(tempFD);
        return nil;
    }

    _fileDescriptor = fileDescriptor;
    close(tempFD);

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self reset];
}

- (void)reset
{
    if (_savedFileDescriptor == -1) return;

    if (close(_fileDescriptor) == -1) {
        NSLog(@"Closing file descriptor %d failed: %s", _fileDescriptor, strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    if (dup2(_savedFileDescriptor, _fileDescriptor) == -1) {
        NSLog(@"Could not restore file descriptor %d: %s", _fileDescriptor, strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    close(_savedFileDescriptor);
    _savedFileDescriptor = -1;
}

@end
```

The initializer either returns a valid instance (redirection established) or `nil`. Call `reset` to restore the redirection immediately.

Both the initializer and `reset` can fail and "lose" the original file descriptor, but the window is small and unlikely. This is probably only relevant when using this class in a multithreaded app (which I don't), so if you intend to use this in a multithreaded environment you want to make sure that only one initializer or `reset` can run at a time using a global mutex or something.

Using this class (which I've got a separate test case for, of course), I can redirect `STDERR_FILENO` to a file and thus catch the output of `NSLog`. This way I can test the unmodified logging class.

Creating a suitable path to a temporary file is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Have the logger output strings. Have another object print these. This way you can unit test the first object separately from the second.

Comment: Interesting idea. Although this would allow me to test whether the output has the desired content, I would still not be able to test whether the output is actually happening.

Comment: The question then is: do you not trust NSLog? You want to write a unites for a function in a system framework?

Comment: It's not about NSLog specifically, actually. It's about testing whether the complete action (log a message) is executed, until the very end. All ideas I've come up with so far (also with your suggestion) only allow me to test a part of the code: there is always going to be some code that I currently cannot test and that thus can be broken accidentally without anyone noticing. I've come up with a design that will reduce the non-testable code to just one trivial line, though. So that's sufficient for me now but I'd prefer a 100% solution.

Comment: I see. The only way to write a unit test for making sure NSLog actually wrote to the console would be to check the console. Not sure how/if you can do that.